# Django: Cannot Update the Value of IntegerField

Tags: django, django-models

I have an IntegerField in my model and I try to update it in the admin page. No matter what value I input (e.g. 100, 200), the value is restored to 0 after saving it.

**models.py**

```
class inputform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=40)
    gender_choices = (
       (0,'Female'), (1,'Male'),
    )
    gender = models.SmallIntegerField('Gender', choices=gender_choices, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField('Age', blank=True, null=True) 
    email = models.CharField('email', max_length=64, blank=True)
    live_choices = (
        (0,'Other'), (1,'Live alone'), (2,'Live with family'), 
    )
    live = models.SmallIntegerField('Living Status', choices=live_choices, blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myApp.models import inputForm

class inputForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id','name', 'age', 'gender')
```

I have tried change the value via SQL in the database directly and it updated successfully. However, when I read it in the admin page and saved it without any change, the value restore to 0.
Is there any wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Can you send the full class ? Maybe some conflict or issues with the saving method .

Comment: Yeah, it would help if you added the model class and the view functions (or admin classes) to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated the full class in the model.py and admin.py in the question. This problem also happen to all smallIntegerField with choices.